# Acura TL 2001 squeaking noise

Tags: noise, suspension, steering, acura, struts

Worried student here! I bought an Acura TL 2001 about 7 months ago and the car was mechanically sound. About a month and a half ago i started to hear a squeaking noise. The noise only occurs when the wheel is in neutral position and I turn it only a little bit to the left and to the right (not even close to a full turn). I can replicate the noise by parking the car with the wheel in neutral position and applying all my body weight to the front left area of the car. The weird part is if I turn the wheel a 360 degrees left or right and apply my body weight the sound does not come out no matter how many times I jump on it. Could it be the ball joint? Or something with the wheel hub? Or is my suspension at fault? Somebody also said that it might be the struts.

Comment: Does it occur with the engine off as well?

Comment: Yes it does, especially when its off.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this particular model suffers from this issue in cold climates. This is due to the factory o-ring failing to provide a good seal and thus allowing air to enter the Power Steering Pump Inlet.
The fix is to replace the o-ring. A step by step guide to this is provided in this [link](http://acurazine.com/forums/problems-fixes-114/diy-105-power-steering-whine-fix-754586/)

Comment: Would the O-ring also be responsible for the noise i get when I don't turn the wheel but instead apply my weight on the front of the car?

Comment: Oh no, sorry, I doubt this could be the issue. The problem I assumed you had would only produce the sound with the engine running.